# Haskell HXT splitting up XML data

Tags: haskell, arrows, hxt

I'm pretty new to arrows so go easy on me...

I'm trying to count the number of a specific nodes in an XML file. The XML file is layed out so that under the root, we have a list of scenes and under each scene we have a list of layers which each has a node called 'recs'. I want to count the number of rects in each scene. I don't fully understand how HXT works.

I shall copy an extract of my code that is causing the problem

```
process :: IOSArrow XmlTree [XmlTree]
process getScene >>. map func
    where func a = a >>> getLayer >>> getRec
```

Each of those get functions are of type `IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree`

Why doesn't this work? And how do I fix it?

Error Message:

```
count_dirty.hs:20:16: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Data.Tree.NTree.TypeDefs.NTree XNode’
                     with ‘IOSLA (XIOState ()) a0 XmlTree’
      Expected type: [XmlTree] -> [IOSLA (XIOState ()) a0 XmlTree]
        Actual type: [IOSLA (XIOState ()) a0 XmlTree]
                     -> [IOSLA (XIOState ()) a0 XmlTree]
    • In the second argument of ‘(>>.)’, namely ‘map func’
      In the second argument of ‘(>>>)’, namely ‘getScene >>. map func’
      In the expression:
        readDocument [withValidate no] file >>> getScene >>. map func
   |
20 |   getScene >>. map func
   |                ^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Comment: I've updated the question to include it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring `func` here to be a helper function which takes some `a`, and then computes `a >>> getLayer >>> getRec`.

As

```
getRec :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
(>>>)  :: (Category cat) => cat a b -> cat b c -> cat a c
```

GHC can deduce that `a >>> getRec` means that `cat ~ IOSArrow, b ~ XmlTree, c ~ XmlTree`, leaving the variable `a` with the undecided type `IOSArrow a XmlTree`, and so

```
func :: a -> IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
```

And

```
map :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]

map func :: [a] -> [IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree]
```

Since

```
(>>.) :: a b c -> ([c] -> [d]) -> a b d 

getScene >>. :: ([XmlTree] -> [d]) -> IOSArrow XmlTree d
```

And now GHC is very certain that `a ~ XmlTree, d ~ IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree`, giving

```
getScene >>. map func 
  :: IOSArrow 
       XmlTree 
       (IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree)
```

The issue comes from your `map func` - `>>.` expects a pure function as its second argument. `func`, in your case, is a function producing an arrow, which is not pure.

I guess you might want to use [applyA](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hxt-9.3.1.16/docs/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v:applyA), which lets you generate an arrow from an input, and then apply that arrow, which is exactly what you're doing here. In this case, you'd write

```
process = applyA (getScene >>. map func)
    ...
```

Note that you're working with list arrows, so the type signature would just be

```
process :: IOSArrow XmlTree XmlTree
```

Comment: Thanks! You have helped me fix it!